# How to re-install same version of ubuntu from command line?

Tags: 16.04

I upgraded to ubuntu 16.04 and it didnt come off well. How can I format and install the same version of ubuntu from command line ?

I tried this command and it did not work.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Are you trying to downgrade Ubuntu? What issues are you having with 16.04?

Comment: @PatrickNegus I am not trying to downgrade , Currently my installation have so many UI glitches. for example it does not show check boxes , touchpad not working. etc.